# How to compute the Wealth Lorenz curve with negative values?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, gini, lorenz-curve

I have some data with asset holdings (wealth) of a large group of people. I want to compute the Lorenz curve and Gini coefficient of my population. The problem is that a large fraction of people have negative wealth.

Say I have wealth that ranges from -1 to 4. About 50% of people have 0 or less wealth. The other remaining households have positive values. In this imaginary country, for every lender we have a borrower, so if we add all of the wealth of everybody we would get a total net wealth of zero. How can I compute the Lorenz curve?

My intuition, which I suspect is wrong, is to move the mass of people with negative wealth to zero. That is, the Lorenz curve only starts to move upwards from 0.5 on the x axis onward. Do you have any suggestions or example? [image]

Comment: The assumption that income or wealth is non-negative really is important for this graph. OTOH it's hard to believe that this complication is not discussed in the income inquality literature.

Comment: Where does your "wealth" data come from? Perhaps it was [standardized](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/standardization/info)?

Comment: @GeoMatt22 From a macroeconomic, general equilibrium model (theoretical values). I do have wealth data from the US where a large fraction of households have negative values and I need to compare the results to those of my theoretical model. None of the data is standardized.

Comment: "if we add all of the wealth of everybody we would get a total net wealth of zero" seems wrong if the data are not standardized. There can be some debtors and some debt holders, but the economy as a whole should certainly have positive assets? I do not do economics, but even Wikipedia says ["Normally the mean (or total) is assumed positive, which rules out a Gini coefficient less than zero."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient)

Comment: @GeoMatt22 what you are saying is correct in the real world, where there are many different types of assets and some of the lending can happen between countries. In my theoretical model I have only one asset, private debt, and its a closed economy, so for every lender I need a borrower and netting out their asset positions should be zero, by definition. But even with real world data, how could I standardize wealth so that I can plot a Lorenz Curve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If others like me happen to stumble upon this question as I did I'd like to share my solution.

In [*On the Gini coefficient normalization when attributes with negative values are considered* 2015 by Emanuela Raffinetti, Elena Siletti & Achille Vernizzi](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10260-014-0293-4). There is proposal for a Gini coefficient based on a generalized Lorentz curve.

Consider an example with incomes [-0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7]. Then according to their definition this generalized Gini coefficient becomes the difference in area between two polygons in the Generalized Lorentz curve, see Figure.
[image: Generalized Lorentz curve of example.]

Here the x-values of the points points are simply 0, 1/N,...,1; we define y as the cumulative sum of the sorted incomes and y_lower will share the edges with y while the middle points all are min(y).

So for our example the polygons with vertices (x, y) and (x, y_lower) are defined by (0, 0), (0.25, -0.3), (0.5, -0.2), (0.75, 0.3), (1,1) (orange crosses in figure) and (0, 0), (0.25, -0.3), (0.5, -0.3), (0.75, -0.3), (1,1) (blue dots in figure).

Then the generalized Gini coefficient are the ratio between these two areas.

A few notes:

- There are at least a few other attempts at negative Gini coefficient, see referenced paper that compares against one other.
- This generalized Gini coefficient does not give quite the same values as the regular Gini coefficient (for maximal inequality this becomes 1 instead of 1-1/N).

Answer (score 1):

You may find this reference interesting. In the end, it all depends on whether you are able to find an interpretation of a decreasing Lorenz curve. http://www.jstor.org/stable/2662589